# Eclipse relative ClassPath?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, rad

This is question has been already asked by someone but didnot got required answer , since i am facing this problem now i ask the same ..

I tried changing the following line in my workspace .classpath file to solve a build error that cannot find a referenced project.

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/axis212.jar" sourcepath="/axis212.jar"/>
```

to

```
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/PREVIOUS_DIR/axis212.jar" sourcepath="/PREVIOUS_DIR/axis212.jar"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't actually asked anything, have you? ;]

Comment: You did? good! now, what's the question?

Comment: however the title looks similiar to some other earlier question the example i face is for type kind=lib which is not same as earlier similiar question . so this infact a different question

Comment: when i try first line i get no error but when i tried the changed one refering previous_dir with valid jar placed in PREVIOUS_DIR,  i get error saying why ? - any idea ?  Project 'XXXXX' is missing required library: '\PREVIOUS_DIR\log4j-1.2.14.jar' ...

Answer (score 0):

You could have resolved that (and possibly other potential problems) by never editing the `.classpath` file directly, and using the Java Build Path dialog instead. Try doing that, and then compare the resulting `.classpath` file to what you quoted above, and witness the difference.